# What does this message on your doorstep say?

Tags: cipher

You wake up one morning and head outside to get your mail. However, on your doorstep, you find an encoded message...

[image: image with code]

**What does this message say?**

Comment: this looks very familiar, yet I can't make out what it is or where I saw it...

Comment: is it pigpen cipher?

Comment: yep, pigpen cipher

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quick guess:

> Start by taking a Pigpen cipher, to get `Njwj jwtr jrtx jpnq in wnx jxfjqu`.
> A Caesar cipher with key 21 yields `Iere erom emos ekil di ris esaelp`.
> Read backwards and with proper punctuation, it says 'Please sir, I'd like some more - Erei'.

Comment: maybe that last word

Comment: Erei is a strange name given the reference, agreed.

Comment: man, too fast... I had just completed the pigpen cipher...